# Processing 3 IDE is half cyrillic

Tags: ide, processing

Recently I started to find interest in Processing and decided to download the offical Processing 3 IDE from https://processing.org/download/?processing. But half of the IDE is in cyrillic symbols.

[Screenshot of the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz1yt.png)

I already tried to change the configuration language etc. Also I downloaded the IDE to my workplace notebook and on the notebook the IDE was complete in normal english.

Now I dont know how to fix this problem, because there are no informations about a problem like this with the Processing 3 IDE.

Comment: What language does your computer use? What font? Have you tried downloading it again, restarting your computer, that kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to try - you may have already.

- I know you said you tried changing the config language, but I'm not sure if you changed the "language.txt" file in the directory "C:\Users\**your_username**\AppData\Roaming\Processing". Ensure it only contains one line - "**en**".
- Fresh install of Processing (delete the folder you extracted to **and** the Processing folder in the directory mentioned above, **and** the sketchbook folder, usually in your documents).

**UPDATE:**

This is a solution which has worked for others experiencing this exact issue:

- Download Processing 3.1.1 - https://github.com/processing/processing/releases/tag/processing-0250-3.1.1
- Make sure Processing is not already running
- Rename the java folder in the processing-3.2.3 directory to something else, eg. java_broken
- Copy the java folder from 3.1.1 to the 3.2.3 directory
- Try running the 3.2.3 version of processing.exe